# Converting monthly cumulative data into quarterly

Tags: time-series

I need to find the Quarterly data from the given data.

```
2014Q4  4993132.965

2015Q1  5140845.555
2015M01 5049003.232
2015M02 5065307.768
2015M03 5140845.555
2015Q2  5277126.34
2015M04 5167891.374
2015M05 5247207.985
2015M06 5277126.34
2015Q3  5319375.997
2015M07 5278779.444
2015M08 5313940.526
2015M09 5319375.997
2015Q4  5554332.896
2015M10 5385785.478
2015M11 5443887.255
2015M12 5554332.896
2015    5554332.896
```

The issue is: the quarterly data given here is obviously not quartely. If we look at 2015M12, it is the same as 2015yearly total (which is the right figure).

So, in effect:
- figure for Month3=figure for Q1
-figure for month6=figure for Q2
-figure for Month12=figfor Q4=fig for the whole year

This is continuing year on year.

From what I know from other literature elsewhere, the Q1 here should be approximately equal to Q1figure/3.

I can not figure out how to calculate quarterly data here.

Comment: I do not understand the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like the variable under consideration is a cumulative sum of something. That would be called a *stock* (as opposed to *flow*) variable in economics. For stock variables, the value at a given time point is the same regardless of whether you measure it every month, every quarter or every year.

For example, you may track your own wealth. If you had $100,000 on December 31, 2016, you can say it was your wealth at the end of December 2016, at the end of Q4 of 2016, or just at the end of 2016. In any case you will be right.

Now if you want to convert such a variable from monthly to quarterly, you just delete the first two months of each quarter. So if the monthly series was $a,b,c,d,e,f,\dots$, then you are left with $c,f,\dots$ for the quarterly series.

Comment: Thanks for the answer Richard. There is one more issue here: I am trying to find a ratio of this variable with a second variable which is not measured in this way. So, the yearly total in the case of second variable is simply Q1+Q2+Q3+Q4 unlike the variable mentioned here where the Q4figure=yearlyfigure. So, I need to bring a parity between the two variables to calculate 'quarterly ratios' of the two. Thanks.

Comment: What are these variables, actually? Understanding the context will help answer the question. You have to think whether the ratio of stock to flow has a sensible interpretation, otherwise you may need to convert stock to flow (taking first differences of the stock variable) or flow to stock (cummulatively summing the flow variable) to make the ratio sensible.

Comment: The data that I have provided is for M3 (broad money) and the other series is Nominal GDP. I need to find Financial Depth using: Current quarterM3/ one period lagged GDP

Comment: I am not a macroeconomist, but if there is such a thing as financial depth defined as the ratio $M3_t/GDP_{t-1}$, then I would just calculate it. Is there any difficulty in doing that?

Comment: So.. the problem here is the quarterly ratios that I am getting are not in line with the literature. But, annual ratios are just fine. so, M3 (Q4 2014=yearly2014)/(Q1+Q2+Q3+Q4 GDP 2014) ratio is in line with 'what it should be'. But, quarterly ratios are not. If I look at the data, let say for Month3 (which is also equal to Q1), ideal ratio (in the ball park figure) would be  when I divide Q1 figure by 3 and then use it as: (q1/3)/lagged quarterly GDP.

Comment: My guess is that you have an incorrect definition of financial depth, perhaps you should double-check it. Perhaps it should involve sum rolling sums of the flow variable (GDP), e.g. $M3_t/(GDP_{t-1}+GDP_{t-2}+GDP_{t-3}+GDP_{t-4})$ for quarterly data? That becomes more of a subject-matter question rather than a statistical one.

Comment: The same definition has been used by a number of papers in case of annual observations. But quarterly data has this problem. Though I will check again.Thanks a ton for your time and all the help :)

Comment: Good luck! You may come back and post an update once you figure out what the correct solution was.